# Laravel Cannot get parent of a category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create Category and i want to show the category name and the parent of its but i keep getting this error message:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.

Here is my model:

```php
public $timestamps = false;
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public function categories(){
    return $this->hasMany(category::class);
}

public function childrenCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
}

public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
}
```

And this is my view:

```php
@foreach($categories as $category )
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$category->parent->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: some of your categories dont have a parent category.

Comment: The problem is in the categories that are the parents where category_id is null

Comment: Change the parent name line to `<td>{{$category->parent->name??''}}</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the categories that are the parents where category_id is null

```
@foreach($categories as $category )
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$category->parent != null ? $category->parent->name : ''}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want to get just the categories that have parents you can do it like this in the controller :

```
$categories = Category::whereNotNull('category_id');
```

Comment: You can use whereNotNull like in the updated answer !